# AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() method return value in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have following code:

```
class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SetState));
            Console.ReadLine();
            objAuto.Set();
        }
        static void SetState(object rsevent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting....");
            bool result = objAuto.WaitOne(10000); // 10 seconds
            Console.WriteLine("Finishing..." + result);
        }
    }
```

When I run this code and I hit `Enter`  within 10 secs I get the value `true` in my `result` variable otherwise `false`.

What does this bool value indicates in each scenario...
I also need to know the meaning/use of another overload of `WaitOne` which has a `boolean` argument like following...

```
objAuto.WaitOne(10000,false)
```

The second parameter is `exitContext` what is this what kind of `context` does this exit ?

Comment: Assuming you've read MSDN article for [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) - please explain what you did not understand about it?

Comment: Please do not ask two separate questions in the same post.

Comment: The MSDN article for AutoResetEvent doesn't say what WaitOne() returns, but the article about its base class does. Silly Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value indicates whether the event was signaled within the timeout you specified.  If the return value is true, the event was signaled; if it is false, then the timeout expired.

The boolean argument for `exitContext` indicates whether or not to release the synchronization context in which you invoke this method.  See more [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx).

> The `exitContext` parameter has no effect unless the `WaitOne` method is called from inside a nondefault managed context. This can happen if your thread is inside a call to an instance of a class derived from `ContextBoundObject`. Even if you are currently executing a method on a class that does not derive from `ContextBoundObject`, like `String`, you can be in a nondefault context if a `ContextBoundObject` is on your stack in the current application domain.
>
> When your code is executing in a nondefault context, specifying true for `exitContext` causes the thread to exit the nondefault managed context (that is, to transition to the default context) before executing the `WaitOne` method. The thread returns to the original nondefault context after the call to the `WaitOne` method completes.

Answer (score 1):

If it returns true then the event was fired, if it returns false then the method ended because the timeout was reached, not because the event was fired.  This is stated in the [documentation of that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx).